# Spring Beans Factory Model

Tags: java, spring

/*   Can You please help me? I have just started Spring.

I know about Singleton and prototype but there is third one also . The third is Factory model .
The sample code is:

```
        */
             package com.springinaction.springidol;
            public classStage{
            private Stage(){
            }
            private static classStageSingletonHolder{
            staticStageinstance=newStage();
            }
            public staticStagegetInstance(){
            returnStageSingletonHolder.instance;
            }
            }
   /*         
       // XML is 

            <bean id="theStage"
        class="com.springinaction.springidol.Stage"
        factory-method="getInstance" />

*/
```

What is different between Factory model and singleton and prototype. And when I will use factory model and why?

Comment: private static classStageSingletonHolder{
            staticStageinstance=newStage();
            }       //why this is called Lazily loadsinstance ??

Answer (score 0):

There is two type of factory method in Spring.Read the details in link given below

1. [Static factory method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method)
2. [Instance factory method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method)